# If Option A is selected show Div X, If all other options selected show Div Y using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this is possible since I have never needed to do this but I need to show or hide a US number input field or an International Number input field based on whether or not a country is selected. I don't want to have to specifically call every val="" individually since that seems like a bad way of doing it, but rather use an else if to select anything other than value="US"
such as

if val="US" show US number field else hide

if val="everything else" show International Number field else hide

I have created a working fiddle to clarify what I mean. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cant seem to find a solution this problem

https://jsfiddle.net/gappleton/k5c0xha0/3/

```
<html>
<div class="input-icon country">
<span class="fa fa-globe"></span> 
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option value="USA">United States</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan Republic</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="C2">China Worldwide</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="CD">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon Republic</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GW">Guinea Bissau</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Laos</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FM">Micronesia</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PN">Pitcairn Islands</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="CG">Republic of the Congo</option>
    <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russia</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis Anguilla</option>
    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">SÃ£o TomÃ© and PrÃ­ncipe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="KR">South Korea</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SH">St. Helena</option>
    <option value="LC">St. Lucia</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VA">Vatican City State</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
</select>
</div>

<!-- US Number div-->
<div id="us-number" class="input-icon inline">
    <span class="fa fa-phone-square"></span>
    <input type="tel" value="" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number*" title="Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required />
</div>
<!-- US Number div Hide-->

<!-- US Number div-->
<div id="int-number" class="input-icon inline">
    <span class="fa fa-phone-square"></span>
    <input type="tel" value="" name="phone" placeholder=" Int Phone Number*" title="Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required />
</div>
<!-- US Number div Hide-->
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#us-number').hide();
$('#country').change(function () {
    if ($('#country').val() == "USA") {
        $('#us-number').show();
    } else {
        $('#us-number').hide();
    }
});

$('#int-number').hide();
$('#country').change(function () {
    if ($('#country').val() == "AL") {
        $('#int-number').show();
    } else {
        $('#int-number').hide();
    }
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Reverse the logic, use `!=` (not equal) https://jsfiddle.net/k5c0xha0/4/

Comment: Or better, put everything in the same handler : https://jsfiddle.net/k5c0xha0/5/ (of course there is better ways to code this : https://jsfiddle.net/k5c0xha0/7/)

Comment: thanks i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this scenario in single `change` event function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// jquery multiple selector. Dont need to seperately write hide for us-number & int-number
$('#us-number, #int-number').hide(); 
$('#country').change(function () {
    if ($('#country').val() == "USA") {
    $('#int-number').hide(); // hide international num field
        $('#us-number').show(); //show us num field
    } else {
    $('#int-number').show(); // show international num field
        $('#us-number').hide(); // hide us num field
    }
});
});
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5c0xha0/6/)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by  Koen user can still select `Country` option from dropdown. In that case all the input will go. So added an `else-if` loop to check if value is empty string then hide both the input field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#us-number, #int-number').hide();
$('#country').change(function () {

    if ($('#country').val() == "USA") {
    $('#int-number').hide();
        $('#us-number').show();
    } else if($('#country').val() == ""){ // Added this else if
      $('#us-number, #int-number').hide();
    }
    else {
    $('#int-number').show();
        $('#us-number').hide();
    }
});
});
```

[Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5c0xha0/8/)

Comment: Dont forget that users can select the "Country" option after the first change and in your example it will still show the int-number input.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small library for this purpose a while ago, called `Visiblary`:

```
/*
 * params:
 *     - selector: jQuery selector
 *     - init: function which gets the Visiblary object to initialize it
 *     - events: object/array
 *         - root: a selector which contain all the affected tags, default is "body"
 *         - types: array, which contains the string representation of the events
 *         - selector: inner selector to identify the target set
 *         - handler: handler function
 */
function Visiblary(params) {
    var instance = this;
    if (!params.toggleClass) {
        params.toggleClass = "invisible";
    }
    this.hideAll = function() {
        $(params.selector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.hideSubset = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.hideOnly = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).not(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showAll = function() {
        $(params.selector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showSubset = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showOnly = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).not(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.invert = function() {
        $(params.selector).each(function() {
            $(this).hasClass(params.toggleClass) ? $(this).removeClass(params.toggleClass) : $(this).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        });
        return instance;
    };
    if (!!params.init) {
        params.init(this);
    }
    if (!!params.events) {
        for (var event in params.events) {
            $(!!params.events[event].root ? params.events[event].root : "body").on(params.events[event].types.join(" "), params.events[event].selector, params.events[event].handler);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Example:

```
var actionButtonVisiblary = new Visiblary({
    selector: ".admin-page",
    events: [
        {
            root: "#admin-action-button-container > .button-action",
            types: ["click"],
            handler: function(e) {
                actionButtonVisiblary.showOnly($(this).data("what"));
            }
        }
    ]
});
```